# Define $P(x)\in [\mathbb{R}]$ is a polynomial that satisfy $P(x).P(y)=P(\frac{x+y}{2})^{2}-P(\frac{x-y}{2})^{2}$

Tags: polynomials

Define $P(x)\in [\mathbb{R}]$ is a polynomial that satisfy

$P(x).P(y)=P(\frac{x+y}{2})^{2}-P(\frac{x-y}{2})^{2}$     (1)

Some notes may help you.

It is very clear that with y=0 then (1)$\Leftrightarrow P(x).P(0)=0$

We just need to consider  $P(x)\neq 0$ so $P(0)=0$.

With $y=-x$ then (1)$\Leftrightarrow P(x)=-P(-x)$

Comment: I think you can first show that $P$ must be a first order polynomial. I'm not entirely sure, though...

Comment: I think you could try looking at the asymptotic behavior when $x\to+\infty$ to get some information about the order of $P$

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ is constant, then it is equal to $0$:

---

Otherwise:

When $X \to \infty$
$$
\begin{align}
P(X)^2 = a_n^2 X^{2n} + a_na_{n-1} X^{2n-1} + o(X^{2n-1})
\end{align}
$$

Let $y\in\Bbb R$, with $P(y)\neq 0$. When $x\to +\infty$

$$
\begin{align}
P(x+y)^2 - P(x-y)^2 &= a_n^2 (x+y)^{2n} + a_na_{n-1} (x+y)^{2n-1} \\
&- a_n^2(x-y)^{2n} - a_na_{n-1}(x-y)^{2n-1} + o(x^{2n-1})\\
& =a_n^2x^{2n} + a_n^2 (2n)x^{2n-1}y  + a_na_{n-1} x^{2n-1} \\
&-a_n^2x^n + a_n^2 (2n)x^{n-1}y - a_na_{n-1}x^{2n-1} + o(x^{2n-1})\\
&=4a_n^2 ny x^{2n-1} + o(x^{2n-1})\\
&\approx 4a_n^2 ny x^{2n-1}
\end{align}
$$

And 
$$
\begin{align}
P(2x) P(2y) &\approx P(2y)a_n 2^nx^n \\
4a_n ny x^{2n-1} &\approx P(2y)2^nx^n
\end{align}
$$
Meaning that $2n-1 = n$, so $n=1$ and $4a_1y = P(2y)2$

So $P(2y) = 2a_1y$
$$P(x) = a_1 x $$
Where $a_1$ can be any non zero constant.

Comment: I am getting an equation $P'(x)=P'(0) \times \dfrac{P(2x)}{2 \times P(x)}$

Comment: With P(0)=0 of course.

Comment: @Mann That looks about right, I think. How did you find it?

Comment: In these type of question I usually replace the two variable with other two variable like t,h. Here what i did is, $\frac{x+y}{2}=t$ and $\frac{x-y}{2}=h$
@Farnight

Comment: @Mann Oh, I see it now. $\frac{x+y}{2} = t+h$ and $\frac{x-y}{2}=t$. It then becomes $$\begin{align}
P(2t+h)P(h) &= P(t+h)^2-P(t)^2\\
\frac{P(t+h)-P(t)}{h} &= \frac{P(h)}{h} \frac{P(2t+h)}{P(t)+P(t+h)}
\end{align} $$
And by letting $h\to 0$, you get
$$P'(t) = P'(0)\frac{P(2t)}{2P(t)} $$
That's pretty clever.

Comment: Yes, but then I checked out $P(x)=ax$ is the only possible solution anyway. 
I change that equation to an integral equation $P(t)=\left[\dfrac{P'(0)}{2} \times \int{P(2t) dt} \right]^{\frac{1}{2}}$
And now, since $P(x)=-P(-x)$ , P(x) can contain only odd terms. Finally comparing the maximum power in integral equation yields same.
Thanks though. :) @Farnight